# Symfony2 routing - slug with slashes and pagination

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I use Symfony2 and have structure of categories and subcategories with articles in them. In the lists I use pagination.

If I call a URL like 'category1-slug/4' it works fine and opens a page 4 of the list with articles in Category 1.

But if I want to use a slug like "category1/subcategory3/4", it returns 404, because it takes the whole string as slug - "category1/subcategory3/4".

How should I configure my routing? I want the last digit to be taken for page number. My current definition is:

```
app_article_category:
path:  /articles/{slug}{trailingSlash}{page}
defaults: { _controller: CmsArticleBundle:AppArticle:showItem, page: 1, trailingSlash:"/"}
requirements:
    page:  \d+
    trailingSlash : "[/]{0,1}"
    slug: .*$
```

Answer (score 0):

adding a new route, before the existing one, should do the job :

```
app_article_category_subcategory:
    path:  /articles/{slug_cat}{trailingSlash}{slug_subcat}{trailingSlash}{page}
    defaults: { _controller: CmsArticleBundle:AppArticle:showItem, page: 1, trailingSlash:"/"}
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
        trailingSlash : "[/]{0,1}"
        slug_cat: .*$
        slug_cat: .*$
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be nice if there is a way to have unlimited levels of subcategories.